# Way of using switch and pointer, strange to me

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int counter[5] = {0};
    int *i, c;
    printf("Please enter a string terminated by ENTER key:\n");
    while(i = counter, (c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        switch(c)
        {
          default: continue;
          case 'U'+' ': case 'U': ++ i;
          case 'O'+' ': case 'O': ++ i;
          case 'I'+' ': case 'I': ++ i;
          case 'E'+' ': case 'E': ++ i;
          case 'A'+' ': case 'A': ++*i;
        }
    }
    for(c = 0; c < 5; c++)
       printf("counter[%d] = %d\n", c, counter[c]);

    return 0;
}
```

This code caught my attention for the following reasons

- First do not understand it because the array *counter* appears
  to be the amount of vowels, without having any allocation made for it.
- Second because the last case the pointer i has an asterisk.
- Third because in each case there is a 'A'+' '. Why does it add
  a space to each vowel

Comment: `'A'+' '` means `'a'` and so on. `++ i` means select next counter, `++*i` means increase counter selected.

Comment: I'm not clear can add an answer more detailed

Comment: About array allocation and initialization look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/1847592)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: My fault; braindead - weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) At the start of your loop, '`i`' is being set to point to the first element in the array '`counter`' because:

```
i = counter;
```

is the same as:

```
i = &counter[0];
```

2) Since you don't have any 'break' statements, when you enter a vowel, '`i`' will be incremented to point to one of the elements of the array. For example, if you enter 'O', the pointer '`i`' will be incremented 3 times. Then, since the last set of case statements increments what '`i`' points to and not '`i`' itself, the value of one of the array elements will be incremented.

3) 'A' is the ASCII character 0x41, ' ' is 0x20. 'A' + ' ' is the same as 0x41 + 0x20 which is 0x61 which is the same as 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

The code is intentionally obfuscated.

- Lowercase letters are written as `<Space> + <upper case equivalent>`.
- The pointer `i` is advanced to the correct vowel by walking through a `switch` without `break` statements.

The first part works because of the way the ASCII character table is organized: Upper and lower case letters have a fixed difference of 32, which happens to also be the ASCII value of the space.

The second part just relies on the rules of the C language:

1. When the loop sees a vowel, it starts at the appropriate switch label and "falls through", executing all the subsequent executable statements.
2. Unless the vowel is an `A` or `a`, the pointer `i` was incremented one or more times, so that it points to `counter[1]`, `counter[2]`, etc.
3. The final statement, `++*i`, increments the *value* that the pointer `i` now points to. That's where vowels are counted. For example, if `i` has been incremented twice it points to `counter[2]`, so that's what the `++` increments.

Answer (score 0):

Read about *definition* and *declaration*. The array is well defined. Althought the initializer is an extension for an automatic variable which e.g. gcc supports.

For the cases, I unwrapped that a bit:

```
   switch ( c ) {
      default: continue;
      case 'U'+' ':  // 'u' 
      case 'U': ++ i;
      case 'O'+' ':  // 'o'
      case 'O': ++ i;
      ...
   }
```

This is just a broken variant to check for `'u'` and `'U'`. Broken as it relies on ASCII encoding where `' '` has the decimal index of 32 and lower-case letters have an index 32 higher than uppercase letters. Looks somewhat obfuscated to me and I would not recommend it (for both reasons given).

If there is a problem for the switch as such: remember that the "case labels " are called that intentionally: the code is executed from each label until the end of the statement. So, for `'U'`, i (bad name for a pointer; i is associated with integger types/index by most) is incremented 4 times - which would point past the array!. The last label just increments the corresponding counter (note the additional `*`.

I think that code is hard to read for the occasional reader. I would not write such without absolute need for performance (whereas It might not even perform that well due to the multiple increments). From a student I would not accept that.